# Tuckey URL Rewriting => Issue with ? and & chars

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm currently trying to use Tuckey and Tomcat to rewrite URLs.

At the moment I'm trying to translate

```
myapp.com/track/2340ddkef?dkfkeif&3434
```

to

```
myapp.com?req=track&id=2340ddkef?dkfkeif&3434
```

But after the first ? or & the parameter is cut off and only

```
myapp.com?req=track&id=2340ddkef
```

is send to the servlet. How can I change that behavior? Is that even possible with Tuckey or do I need to apply some filter which to ensure the characters are not lost?

Answer (score 1):

Embedding ? and & in URLs like that really isn't valid. You should URL encode those strings. For example, in Java, use

```
URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: In my case (SEO implentation), the Url will be requested by Google Search Engine, and that will be like 
`http://mysiteurl.com/?_escaped_fragment_=queryParamVal`
Here, I can't skip or ecncode ?. How do I fix this??